# No logging in production environment when running Console commands

Tags: symfony, symfony4, monolog

When running `Console` commands in `prod` mode, I need to log Doctrine related debug messages. Everything works fine in `dev` with the following configuration, so I assume I forgot something to set when in `prod`?

**My system:**

- PHP 7.3
- Symfony 4.4
- Monolog
- Doctrine

**How do I run commands:**

I run commands in `prod` as either

```sh
php bin/console app:scrape --env=prod
```

or

```sh
# set APP_ENV=prod in .env.local before
php bin/console app:scrape
```

Both result in no logs. I am sure, I run `prod`, because Symfony creates `var/cache/prod` every time.

### Monolog configuration file: config/package/prod/monolog.yaml

This file configures Monolog in `prod` environment.

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: debug
            handler: nested
            excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        deprecation:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.deprecations.log"
        deprecation_filter:
            type: filter
            handler: deprecation
            max_level: info
            channels: ["php"]
        doctrine:
            level: debug
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/doctrine/info.log"
            channels: ["doctrine"]
```

**Output of APP_ENV=prod bin/console debug:config monolog**:

https://gist.github.com/k00ni/419f62941e496a376be35a0d06e44131

Comment: You can check if your configuration has the desired effect by running `APP_ENV=prod bin/console debug:config monolog` Can you confirm that the doctrine logger is set up correctly?

Comment: Did you try to set `info` or `debug` for  `action_level: error` in `config/package/prod/monolog.yaml`. Because actually only `ERROR` logs will be written and if you do not have on your console command, then it will write nothing.

Comment: @dbrumann: I added the output of this command at the end of my question. How can i confirm, that the doctrine logger is set up correctly? If i run in `dev`, it logs all Doctrine output, so i assume it is set up correctly?

Comment: @GrenierJ: i used `debug` in `config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml`, but nothing was logged. I assume that `config/packages/monolog.yaml` is the important config file, isn't it? Could `config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml` be interfering?

Comment: `config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml` override(and complete) default configuration of `config/packages/monolog.yaml` ( like say in the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-environments)

Comment: Can you trigger a deprecation in your command to see if it is logged to deprecation.log? I have posted a preliminary answer to better format the config, but I am not sure it will work. Please try it out and report back, so I can delete the answer if it doesn't help.

Comment: @GrenierJ: I updated the question based on your feedback. I removed `config/packages/monolog.yaml`, even though its part shouldn't be overridden by `config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml`. Also added the Doctrine part to `config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml`.

Comment: @GrenierJ the prod config does not override the other configuration, at least not in the sense that it will replace the other handlers. It would only override other handlers when they are defined in both places. They are both merged as can be seen in the gist.

Comment: @dbrumann:  I hope its OK, that i keeping answering here. I changed the Console command so that it doesn't return anything, which triggered a deprecation. It wrote the deprecation information in `var/log/prod.deprecation.log` as well as in `var/log/doctrine/info.log`. But not my expected Doctrine debug information (like SQLs).

Comment: Then at least we know that this handler works. Can you also try triggering an error/exception to see whether it will be logged to the prod.log and/or info.log? My current assumption is, that Doctrine uses the default logger with the main handler instead of your doctrine handler. So raising an exception (preferrably after a doctrine query) to make sure the doctrine messages still land in main, but not in your doctrine log would indicate that this is actually what's happening

Comment: @dbrumann: raising an exception inside the console command resulted in the error message as well as a debug information: `[2020-02-26 17:43:18] console.ERROR: Error thrown while running command "app:scrape --mode=next". Message: "Test" {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Test at /var/www/html/src/App/Console/Scrape.php:102)","command":"app:scrape --mode=next","message":"Test"} []
[2020-02-26 17:43:18] console.DEBUG: Command "app:scrape --mode=next" exited with code "1" {"command":"app:scrape --mode=next","code":1} []
` in both `var/log/prod.log` as well as `var/log/doctrine/info.log`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could have a main handler that is grouped so that it will pass messages with both handlers (your current main and doctrine):

```
# config/packages/monolog.yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: group
            members: ["doctrine", "default"]
        doctrine:
            level: debug
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/doctrine/info.log"
            channels: ["doctrine"]
```

```
# config/package/prod/monolog.yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        default: # formerly main
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: nested
            excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        deprecation:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.deprecations.log"
        deprecation_filter:
            type: filter
            handler: deprecation
            max_level: info
            channels: ["php"]
```